# Android C++ - socket select is driving me nuts! why is it not respecting the timeout value I specify?

Tags: android, sockets, android-ndk

I have a loop in a thread. At the beginning of each loop cycle, I define a socket set and then I use select to wait for activity on any of the sockets in the socket set. I have set the time out value to 2 sec and 500ms. For some reason, the 'select' function returns immediately (like after 1ms) and it doesn't seem to respect the time-out value I defined. So what am I doing wrong?

Here's the code snippet:

```
/* Define a time-out value of 2 seconds and 500ms */
struct timeval sock_timeout;
sock_timeout.tv_sec = 2;
sock_timeout.tv_usec = 500 * 1000;

while (m_keepRunning)
{
  fd_set UdpSocketSet;
  SOCKET maxfd = INVALID_SOCKET;
  std::map<uint16_t, UdpChannel*>::iterator k;

  /* Define socket set */
  pthread_mutex_lock(&m_udpChannelsMutex);
  FD_ZERO(&UdpSocketSet);
  for (k = m_udpChannels.begin(); k != m_udpChannels.end(); ++k)
  {
     UdpChannel* thisUdpChannel = k->second;
     FD_SET(thisUdpChannel->m_udpRxSocket, &UdpSocketSet);
     if (maxfd == INVALID_SOCKET)
     {
        maxfd = thisUdpChannel->m_udpRxSocket;
     }
     else
     {
        if (thisUdpChannel->m_udpRxSocket > maxfd) maxfd = thisUdpChannel->m_udpRxSocket;
     }
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&thisAudioStreamer->m_udpChannelsMutex);

  /* TIMES OUT LITERALLY EVERY MILLISECOND!!! WHY????? */
  int retval = pal_select(maxfd + 1, &UdpSocketSet, NULL, NULL, (timeval*)&sock_timeout);
```

UPDATE:

I hate Android Studio. It doesn't pick up incremental changes, so I was launching the same app over and over again without noticing that it didn't pick up the changes in the native library.

EJP's suggestion must have helped because once I did a clean rebuild of the apk  with EJP's suggested change, the problem went away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reset the socket timeout struct every time around the loop. From *man select* (Linux):

> select() may update the timeout argument to indicate how much time was left.